# Excel vba to delete a single row until a specific column

Tags: excel, insert, rows, delete-row, vba

I have an excel sheet application in which I need to delete a `row` from `Column 'A'` to `Column 'M'` only, as there are certain data from `Column 'N'`. A delete statement to delete only that range. For example, if I have data in row `9`, I want to delete `A9` to `M9` and the columns from `N9` should not be affected. Similarly, an insert statement to shift cells from `A9` to `M9` only.

Answer (score 0):

A simple statement to delete the info from A9 to M9

```
Sheets("yourSheetName").Range("A9:M9").ClearContents
```

If you move the resulting cells up one row, it's going to throw your data out of sync with what's in N9 to N?, unless it doesn't matter.
To delete AND shift up

```
Sub Delete_Range_To_ShiftUp() 
   Range("A9:M9").Delete Shift:=xlUp 
End Sub
```

To insert a range only (not an entire row) try this

```
Sub Insert_Range_To_ShiftDown()
   Range("A9:M9").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Comment: if i would need to add a new row in only that range, that is from A9 to M9, then what would be the insert statement.

Comment: @Sindhu I've edited my answer to accommodate your last request. Please select my answer if this works for you !